# CGAL Voronoi Diagram for Segments

Tags: cgal

I have used a CGAL Segment_Delaunay_graph to create a voronoi diagram for a collection of line segments.  I would like to extract the edges of the Segment_Delaunay_graph which correspond to the voronoi cells.  There are methods draw_dual() and draw_skeleton() for this purpose, but both include some additional edges that I don't want to retain (and draw_skeleton removes some edges that I do want to retain).

Here is an image to show the issue:

[example voronoi diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8sC7.png)

The black lines are inputs.  They are typically groups of several segments connected end-to-end to form longer lines, although each segment is input to the Segment_Delaunay_graph individually like this:

```
s 1677850.1951146198 466276.4198628192  1784307.2726912862 466276.4198628192
s 1784307.2726912862 466276.4198628192  1784307.2726912862 567677.3831007502
s 1784307.2726912862 567677.3831007502  1677850.1951146198 567677.3831007502
```

The red and blue lines are output by draw_dual().  I want to retain the red lines which represent voronoi cell boundaries around the connected input lines, but I do not want to keep the blue lines.  **Is is possible to filter out the unwanted edges based on information stored in the Segment_Delaunay_graph?  If so, how?**

Some sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_filtered_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Segment_Delaunay_graph_2.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_filtered_traits_2<K>  Gt;
typedef CGAL::Segment_Delaunay_graph_2<Gt>             SDG2;

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //read line segments from input file
    string inFile = "example-a.in";
    ifstream ifs(inFile);

    SDG2          sdg;
    SDG2::Site_2  site;

    std::vector<SDG2::Site_2> sites;
    while (ifs >> site) {
        sites.push_back(site);
    }

    ifs.close();

    //add line segments to diagram
    sdg.insert(sites.begin(), sites.end(), CGAL::Tag_true());

    //save voronoi edges to a file
    string outFile = "example-a.out";
    ofstream ofs(outFile);

    sdg.draw_dual(ofs);

    ofs.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I observe the red lines you want to keep. Are they the edges that far away to the sites that are not the junction sites? You can set a distance threshold *d*, if the distance between the edge to its closest site is smaller than *d* and the site is not a junction, then remove this edge.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I haven't seen a distance threshold option in the CGAL Segment_Delaunay_graph.  Is this option built in to CGAL?

Comment: You can implement it by yourself. You can only save the edges by setting if (squared_distance( segment, v[i]->site()), where     SDG2::Vertex_handle v[] = { e.first->vertex( sdg.ccw(e.second) ), e.first->vertex( sdg.cw(e.second) ), e.first->vertex( e.second ), sdg.tds().mirror_vertex(e.first, e.second) };    CGAL::Segment_2<K> segment(e.first, e.second); reference:http://compgeom.inf.usi.ch/doc_output/Segment_Delaunay_graph_Linf_2/Segment_Delaunay_graph_Linf_2_2sdg-voronoi-edges_8cpp-example.html